# $('input[name = "shippingaddress" , id='this.id']').val()

Tags: php, jquery, html, dom

Is there any possibility to get a value of input element by NAme and ID

Example

```
$('input[name="shippingaddress" , id='this.id']').val()
```

Update from comment:

I have a code like this

```
$("select[name='shipmentaddress[]']").click(function(e){ 
    var s = this.id; 
    alert(this.id);     //gets id shipmentaddress    
    alert($('select[name=shippingaddress], select[id=s]').val()); 
});
```

Comment: Yes, but why would you want to? IDs are unique...

Comment: Why not just write `$('#yourId').val()`

Comment: i have a code like this 

$("select[name = 'shipmentaddress[]']").click(function(e){ 

var s = this.id;
     alert(this.id); //gets id shipmentaddress  
     alert($('select[name=shippingaddress], select[id = s]').val());
});

Answer (score 1):

You are basically using the selectors wrongly.

Try,

```
$('#' + this.id +'[name="shippingaddress"]').val();
```

Since we are using an id we dont need to add anymore identities to it.

```
$('#' + this.id).val()
```

Or, less wastefully:

```
this.value;
```

Comment: Question is, why would you want anything more specific than an ID?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Ah.. You are right..! There is no need of the attribute selector here..!

Comment: Then why not: `this.value`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol The better/more important question is why on earth would you use `this.id` to form an ID selector - *you already have a reference to the element you want*.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Usually I pick up on that XD I must be tired.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `id` attribute/property on an element is supposed to be unique throughout the document, so combining an ID selector with anything else is quite often pointless. Unless it's possible for you to only ever generate a *single* element with a given ID, but it may have a different name depending on some conditions. Assuming that's not the case, you could just do:

```
$('#your-id').val();
```

However, it seems like you want the ID of the element to be dynamic, and to match the value of `this.id` (whatever `this` happens to be). That is - because as I explained above about IDs being unique - completely redundant; you already *have* a reference to the element with that ID in `this`, so just do:

```
this.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

$(this).attr("name")

$(this).attr("id")

Will return name and id values respectively.

I think the OP wants to get the id of a clicked element.

Comment: Not what is being asked.

Comment: I think it is... the OP isn't really very clear on what they want to achieve, though. I think the OP wants the ID and the NAME of the element that's been clicked, therefore my answer is what he wants, if not, then fair play. But arguing with everyone else's answer and not giving one yourself is pretty pointless

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. you need to write like this (please correct your id, I have given some dummy id) :

```
$('input[name="shippingaddress"][id="inputId"]').val()
```

But if you have `id` then you can directly use it to get value like below (provided that you must have unique `id` through out the DOM structure )

```
$('#inputId').val()
```

Comment: You would never do `[id="inputId"]` as it is much slower to search than `#inputid` (which uses an id table).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, yes you are right. But I answered the PO's question to use id as selector in jquery and after that added to search by id only if id present.

Comment: Fair enough... The original is "odd" :)

Answer (score 0):

Id is `unique` `this.value` is enough .why the others are trying different selector

Comment: Enna nadanthuchu nu keka phone panna, ennada respond panra nee..? Nalla friendu ...!

Comment: I did't say anything to him